# ListTile with additional image

Tags: flutter

it is possible to configure a ExpansionTile/ListTile using a Card widget to look similar to this:

[image]

Basically on top of left image, title, subtitle and trailing, I would like to have a second image/text between title and trailing.

```
return Card(
    child: ExpansionTile(
      leading: ListImage(
        image: "Image",
      ),
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text("Title"),
        ],
      ),
      subtitle: Text("subtitle"),
      trailing: Column(
        children: [
          Text('11'),
        ],
      ),
      children: [],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: can you include your current snippet?

Comment: added an example @Md.YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `Row` as a trailing widget to get the desired result.[image]

```
Card(
    child: ExpansionTile(
      title: const Text('Title'),
      subtitle: const Text('SubTitle'),
      leading: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'),
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        ],
      ),
      children: const [
        Text('Child 1'),
        Text('Child 2'),
        Text('Child 3'),
      ],
    ),
  )
```